# Combining tables in SQL (only for for certain rows)

Tags: sql, where-clause

I wasn't even sure how to word this in the subject line. However, I have a SELECT statement that pulls information from an SQL view called CONTACTS (F_ame, L_Name, Address, Email, etc...). I have another view called INVOICES with purchase information for the members in the contacts view. Keep in mind that the INVOICES view has mulitple purchases of varying products for each member. These two views can be linked with a ContactID key

I only need to display a certain product (EADP Package), if purchased, from the INVOICES view on the same line as the member who purchased it. I also need to retain the entire member list in the pull. So, if I use a WHERE clause to only pull that product, It only gives me those who purchased that product. I need to keep the entire member list and still have a column that displays that particular product for those who purchased it. Hope that made sense.

Sorry, but there are 3 views, not 2. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT     Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Contact.CFSDesignation, Contact.EMailAddress1, Contact.Telephone1, Contact.DefaultPriceLevelIdName
FROM         Contact INNER JOIN
                      FilteredInvoice ON Contact.ContactId = FilteredInvoice.contactid INNER JOIN
                      FilteredInvoiceDetail ON FilteredInvoice.invoiceid = FilteredInvoiceDetail.invoiceid
WHERE     (Contact.DefaultPriceLevelIdName = 'member') AND FilteredInvoiceDetail.productidname = 'eAudiology 2014 Unlimited On-Demand Package'
```

This works fine,but only pulls those who purchased the package. I need the entire member list from CONTACTS (about 10,000 records) plus the product column showing the product above for those who purchased it. I belive is has something to do with joins, but can't get my head around it.

Getting Close, but it doesn't like the keyword "ON":

Also. in your previous answer, what are "C" and "I" used for?

```
SELECT     Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Contact.CFSDesignation, Contact.EMailAddress1, Contact.Telephone1, Contact.DefaultPriceLevelIdName
FROM         Contact  LEFT JOIN
                      FilteredInvoice ON Contact.ContactId = FilteredInvoice.contactid LEFT JOIN (SELECT FilteredInvoiceDetail.productidname
                      FROM FilteredInvoiceDetail
                      WHERE productidname = 'eAudiology 2014 Unlimited On-Demand Package') ON FilteredInvoice.invoiceid = FilteredInvoiceDetail.invoiceid
WHERE     (Contact.DefaultPriceLevelIdName = 'member')
```

Comment: do you know what `JOIN`s are?

Comment: You can use Inner Join here to pull the entire information regarding members and their purchases.

Comment: I did use an Inner Join to pull together the two views, but trying to extract a certain purchase for those who purchased it and still retaining the entire list has proved to be a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Contacts C 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * 
            FROM Invoices
            WHERE Product = 'EADP Package') I
    ON C.ContactID = I.ContactID
```

Comment: Thanks Lamak. Will give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Lamak, I edited my previous post above with additional information. I think I understand the LEFT JOIN and nested SELECT statement, but am unsure where it goes in my original SELECT statement.

Comment: @Cygnus-X1 Change your first `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` and the second `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN (SELECT .....)`. Don't forget to move the `productidname = 'eAudiology 2014 Unlimited On-Demand Package'` filter inside that nested `SELECT`

Comment: Getting closer, but it throws an error on the keyword "ON". See above. Does is have something to do with using 3 views and not 2?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction (LEFT JOINS). I just needed to learn up a little on the use of LEFT JOINS.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me:

SELECT DISTINCT    Contact.ContactId,Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Contact.CFSDesignation, Contact.EMailAddress1, Contact.DefaultPriceLevelIdName, productidname
FROM         Contact  LEFT JOIN
                      FilteredInvoice ON Contact.ContactId = FilteredInvoice.contactid LEFT JOIN (SELECT FilteredInvoiceDetail.productidname, FilteredInvoiceDetail.invoiceid
                      FROM FilteredInvoiceDetail
                      WHERE productidname = 'eAudiology 2014 Unlimited On-Demand Package' OR productidname = 'eAudiology 2014 Unlimited On-Demand Pkg Renewal')  I ON FilteredInvoice.invoiceid = I.invoiceid

WHERE     (Contact.DefaultPriceLevelIdName = 'member' OR DefaultPriceLevelIdName = 'student')

ORDER BY LastName